# How to validate child objects by implementing IDataErrorInfo on parent class

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I am developing a WPF Application using MVVM Architecture. I am an amateur in WPF so bear with me..

I have two model classes. Parent class has an object of another (child) class as its property. (i mean nested objects and not inherited objects)

For instance, consider the following scenario.

```
public class Company
{

   public string CompanyName {get; set;}

   public Employee EmployeeObj {get; set;}
}

public class Employee 
{

   public string FirstName {get; set;}

   public string LastName {get; set;}

}
```

I want to validate the properties of Employee entity using Enterprise Library Validation Block.

I was able to do it by implementing IDataErroInfo interface in employee class as shown below

```
public class Employee :  IDataErrorInfo

{

   [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate="First Name is mandatory"]
   public string FirstName {get; set;}

   [StringLengthValidator(0,20,MessageTemplate="Invalid")]
   public string LastName {get; set;}

   public string Error
   {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

            ValidationResults results = Validation.ValidateFromAttributes<Employee>(this);

            foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
            {
                error.AppendLine(result.Message);
            }

            return error.ToString();
        }

    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            ValidationResults results = Validation.ValidateFromAttributes<Employee>(this);

            foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Key == propertyName)
                {
                    return result.Message;
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont want to implement IDataErroInfo for every child model i create.

Is there any way to validate the Employee object by implementing IDataErrorInfo on the parent (Company) class ?

And also is there any triggers to start validation of objects. I would like to validate the objects only when i want to and not all the time.

Comment: Note that the IDataErrorInfo should be implemented in the ViewModel, not in the Model.

Comment: yes that would be one option. but if i do so, i have to create a property in viewmodel for every property i have in model. Right now, i have the model object itself as the property and am binding the view controls to the model directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can absolutely implement `IDataErrorInfo` on a base class using Validation Application Block. [Here is an article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=82) that describes how to. The code basically comes down to this:

```
public abstract class DataErrorInfo : IDataErrorInfo
{
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(columnName);
            return this.GetErrorInfo(prop); 
        }
    }

    private string GetErrorInfo(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        var validator = this.GetPropertyValidator(prop);

        if (validator != null)
        {
           var results = validator.Validate(this);

           if (!results.IsValid)
           {
              return string.Join(" ",
                  results.Select(r => r.Message).ToArray());
           }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    private Validator GetPropertyValidator(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        string ruleset = string.Empty;
        var source = ValidationSpecificationSource.All;
        var builder = new ReflectionMemberValueAccessBuilder();
        return PropertyValidationFactory.GetPropertyValidator(
            this.GetType(), prop, ruleset, source, builder);
    }
}
```

You can use this abstract class add validation behavior to your entities by inheriting from it:

```
public partial class Customer : DataErrorInfo
{
}
```