# How to validate child objects by implementing IDataErrorInfo on parent class and how to bind validation to objects

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

I want to ask exactly the same question that was asked in this link and also a person answered too but I couldn't understand how to incorporate that in the code. Sorry for asking the noob question, please bear with me.

the link for the question is [How to validate child objects by implementing IDataErrorInfo on parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321723/how-to-validate-child-objects-by-implementing-idataerrorinfo-on-parent-class?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Question is exactly the same and answer is how to achieve but what I find lacking is how to use that class for validation in Employee class.

I'm posting the same question below:
I have two model classes. Parent class has an object of another (child) class as its property. (i mean nested objects and not inherited objects)

```
public class AddEditItemVM
{
    #region Properties/Fields

    //validate here: Category cannot be empty, it has to be selected
    public Category SelectedCategory
    {
        get => _SelectedCategory;
        set 
        { 
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCategory));
        }
    }
    private Category _SelectedCategory = new CCategory();

    public Items Source
    {
        get => _Source;
        set 
        { 
            _Source = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Source));
        }
    }
    private Items _Source = new Items();

    #endregion Properties/Fields
}
```

Category class is

```
public class Category 
{
    #region Properties/Fields

    public long Id
    {
        get => _Id;
        set
        {
            _Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }
    long _Id;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name;
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
    private string _Name;

    #endregion Properties/Fields
}
```

Items class is

```
public class Items
{
    #region Properties/Fields

    public int CategoryID
    {
        get => _CategoryID;
        set
        {
            _CategoryID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CategoryID));
        }
    }
    int _CategoryID;
    
    //I want to validate this, item name cannot be empty and cannot greater than 20 characters
    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name;
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }
    string _Name = String.Empty;

    //validate for percentage like percentage should be between 1 and 100
    public decimal? TaxPerc
    {
        get => _TaxPerc;
        set
        {
            //_TaxPerc = value;
            _TaxPerc = Properties.Settings.Default.GSTPerc;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TaxPerc));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PricePlsTax));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TaxAmount));
        }
    }
    decimal? _TaxPerc = null;

    //price cannot be 0
    //* required field!
    public decimal? Price
    {
        get => _Price;
        set
        {
            _Price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PricePlsTax));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TaxAmount));
        }
    }
    decimal? _Price = null;
    #endregion Properties/Fields
}
```

and the person answered with validation with IDataErrorInfo (which is what I want)

```
public abstract class DataErrorInfo : IDataErrorInfo
{
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(columnName);
            return this.GetErrorInfo(prop); 
        }
    }

    private string GetErrorInfo(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        var validator = this.GetPropertyValidator(prop);

        if (validator != null)
        {
           var results = validator.Validate(this);

           if (!results.IsValid)
           {
              return string.Join(" ",
                  results.Select(r => r.Message).ToArray());
           }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    private Validator GetPropertyValidator(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        string ruleset = string.Empty;
        var source = ValidationSpecificationSource.All;
        var builder = new ReflectionMemberValueAccessBuilder();
        return PropertyValidationFactory.GetPropertyValidator(
            this.GetType(), prop, ruleset, source, builder);
    }
}
```

but I couldn't understand the final part i.e. implementation I mean how to use this class in the implemented class. He said to implement it by making it the parent class which is as below

```
public AddEditItemVM : DataErrorInfo
{
}
```

**but I wanna know how to bind the validation with the objects.**

Comment: You would add your properties like "public Category SelectedCategory" like you had above, and then you would use annotations like "[Required]" on the name property (since you don't want it empty) and then something like [MaxLength(20)] on the name property as well since you don't want it longer than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>
```

This will bind to your name property of your selectedcategory class and show if there is any validation errors.